# Energy Calculation using Arduino

Tags: arduino, calculation, energy

How I can calculate  accurate energy   if I have  Power, Current , Voltage  values

This is the code of energy calculation, the result's it's wrong  so how I can fix that

I want to measure apparent energy, I don't have a problem in V , I, P values

```
if(millis() >= energyLastSample + 1)                                                
          {
            energySampleCount = energySampleCount + 1;  
            energyLastSample = millis(); 
          }
          if(energySampleCount >= 1000)
          {                                                       
            apparent_energy_l1 = apparent_power_l1/3600.0;                                            
            finalEnergyValue_l1 = finalEnergyValue_l1 + apparent_energy_l1;
            
            apparent_energy_l2 = apparent_power_l2/3600.0;                                            
            finalEnergyValue_l2 = finalEnergyValue_l2 + apparent_energy_l2;
            
            apparent_energy_l3 = apparent_power_l3/3600.0;                                            
            finalEnergyValue_l3 = finalEnergyValue_l3 + apparent_energy_l3;
            
          //  Serial.print(finalEnergyValue,2); 
         //  Serial.println("test"); 
            energySampleCount = 0 ;                                                           
         }
           energy_total=  finalEnergyValue_l1+finalEnergyValue_l2+finalEnergyValue_l3;
}
```

Some tips about power calculation using Arduino or any microcontroller,
open-source code or project,
guidelines  to solve my problem

Comment: better to ask on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could you add an example of the output? "Wrong" is a broad problem description and it is unlikely that someone can identify a problem based on that description.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that energy (W x t) is a measurement of power over time, while power is a measurement of work, meaning that you cannot simply divide power by 3600 (which would be the factor to convert from seconds to hours) to get an energy value. Power (W) is a measurement of how much work for example a device is currently doing. If you want to calculate the Energy consumed by a device, you will have to continuously measure the Power, for example in 1s intervals, and add it to a counter. Then you have a value which represents Ws - Watt seconds. You can then calculate the Wh consumed from that value.

**Example:**
You have a device which consumes 300W of power. You keep that device running for exactly 3 hours. If you measure the power consumption every second as described, you will have measured 3240000 Ws. 3240000 Ws / 3600 =  900Wh / 1000 = 0,9 kWh. You can of course change your measurement interval to fit your needs in regard to accuracy.

**Pseudocode:**

```
if ( millis() >= lastmillis + 1000 )
    {
        lastmillis = millis();
        wattseconds = wattseconds + power; #increment energy counter by current power
        kilowatthours = wattseconds / 3600000; 
        print(kilowatthours)
    }
```

You could of course use a [one second interrupt](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/29873/how-to-set-up-one-second-interrupt-isr-for-ds3231-rtc) with an external RTC to get a more accurate timing.